# Android Studio Beta 2 not showing XML layout preview

Tags: android, android-studio, jetbrains-ide, android-studio-3.0

I am using android studio Beta 2 version which is not showing XM Layout preview at all.Any help will be appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using Beta, that mean not stable and there will be some bug. So download latest version of Android studio. Now Android studio 3.0 Beta 6 available. Update and try.

You can download here: https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html